# Consider defining a bean of type 'form' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, annotations, javabeans

Place that is complaining the error:

```
@Data
public class AluguelValorForm {
    
    @Autowired
    private ValorAluguelMultaService valorAluguelMultaService;
    
    @NotNull @NotEmpty
    private String idAluguel;
    
    @NotNull 
    private Double valor;


    public AluguelValor converter(AluguelValorRepository aluguelValorRepository, AluguelForm form ) {
        Double valorAluguel = valorAluguelMultaService.valorAluguel(form);
        return new AluguelValor(idAluguel,valorAluguel);
    }
    
    public AluguelValor update(String idAluguel,Double valor) {
        AluguelValor aluguelValor = new AluguelValor();
        
        aluguelValor.setId(idAluguel);
        aluguelValor.setValor(valor);
        
        return aluguelValor;
        
    }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AluguelValorRepository extends MongoRepository<AluguelValor, String> {
    
    Aluguel getReferenceById(String id);

}
```

Place that I call the method in AluguelValorForm:

```
@PostMapping
//@CacheEvict(value = "listaDeTopicos",allEntries = true)
public void cadastrar(@RequestBody  AluguelForm form) {
    Optional<Carro> carro = carroRepository.findByPlaca(form.getPlaca_carro());
    Optional<Cliente> cliente = clienteRepository.findByCpf(form.getCpf());
    
    if(carro.isPresent() && cliente.isPresent()) {
        Aluguel aluguel2 = form.converter(aluguelRepository);
        aluguelRepository.save(aluguel2);
        
        Double valorAluguel = valorAluguelMultaService.valorAluguel(form);
        AluguelValor aluguelValor = aluguelValorForm.update(aluguel2.getId(), valorAluguel);
        
        
        aluguelValorRepository.save(aluguelValor);
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Field aluguelValorForm in projeto.locadora.locadora.controllers.AluguelController required a bean of type 'projeto.locadora.locadora.controller.form.AluguelValorForm' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Apparently, it's not possible to @Autowired a class that doesn't have any bean, like my RentValue. That's why I got this error.